# How could I refactor my method?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, refactoring

I have the code and thinking about making it more pure and clean.

I feel that it would be good to get rid of multiple returns in the method.

How could it be possibly refactored?
Maybe I should use some pattern?
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

```
class Test{    
          private client;
          private concreteMixer;
          constructor(client, concreteMixer){
            this.client = client;
            this.concreteMixer = concreteMixer;
          }

          public method(){
            let form = new Form();
            if(form.isSubmitted()){
              if(form.isValid()){

                let field = form.getField();
                let infoField = this.client.testField(field);
                if(!infoField){
                  form.setError('This is not valid field');
                  return form;
                }

                let coffee = this.concreteMixer.makeСoffee();
                //two days have passed
                if(!coffee){
                  form.setError('I want coffee');
                  return form;
                }

                this.concreteMixer.pourInThermosBottle();
                //two days have passed

                return coffee;
              }
            }

            return form;
          }
        }
```

Comment: You'll probably be better posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that

```
    /**
     * Comment
     */
    class Test {
      /**
       * Comment
       */
      protected client;

      /**
       * Comment
       */
      protected concreteMixer;

      /**
       * Comment
       */
      constructor(client, concreteMixer) {
        this.client = client;

        this.concreteMixer = concreteMixer;
      }

      /**
       * Comment
       */
      public method() {
        const form = new Form();

        // Comment
        if (!form.isSubmitted() || !form.isValid()) {
          return form;
        }

        // Comment
        const field = form.getField();

        // Comment
        const infoField = this.client.testField(field);

        // Comment
        if (!infoField) {
          form.setError(ERROR_CODE_01);

          return form;
        }

        // Comment
        const coffee = this.concreteMixer.makeСoffee();

        //two days have passed
        if (!coffee) {
          form.setError(ERROR_CODE_02);

          return form;
        }

        // Comment
        this.concreteMixer.pourInThermosBottle();

        // two days have passed

        return coffee;
      }
    }
```

---

I replaced the `let` occurency by `const`. When your variable doesn't change use of const. When it does use of `let`.

---

When you have a condition like :

```
if (something) { 
   ... a lot of lines
} 

// end of function
```

You can use :

```
 if (!something) { 
    return;
 }
```

So you win an indentation level for a lot of lines.

---

Use of Errors codes instead of straight error strings. So the user of your app can treat it in a programmatic way.

---

Comment your code to explain what's happening. So if a fellow coder or your future yourself discover this code it'll be easier to understand. At least: **What does the class do?** **What does the `method` do?**

---

I replaced `private` by `protected` so if someday you want to inherit from your class you can do it without further change.

Comment: And what is _that_ precisely? You provided no explanation.

Comment: That does look like refactored to me. Formatted a bit maybe, but you still have a method that returns `coffee` in one case and a `Form` in another seems like a major red flag to me.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I didn't touched the logic. Idk how it's used. Your point is legit :) K. igor should have a look.

Comment: Reformatting is not refactoring. From wikipedia: "Code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code - changing the factoring - without changing its external behavior".